# Производительность JNI: правда или миф?

Tags: java, c++, jni

С учебы мне говорят то, что *JNI* это *c++*. И по скорости выполнения он превосходит *Java*. Но капаюсь я в нём и, как оказалось, вызов *JNI* это очень трудаемкая задача. И она требует до 12 проходов (шагов). Стоит ли вообще его использовать? И есть ли конкретные случаи когда он в *Java* так необходим?

Comment: Так как вызов - это трудоемкая задача, то смысл как раз в том, чтобы вынести критичные по скорости участки в быстрый код, но не вызывать его часто.

Comment: minecraft pe (андроид) на 99% на нем написан. трудоемкая она в плане неудобства для программиста, но не в плане скорости

Comment: По поводу внутристрочного выделения кода написано на [Мете](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1328/176217).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Прямо с сайта [Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/intro.html#wp9502):

Примеры, когда следует использовать JNI:

1. Стандартная библиотека JAVA не поддерживает платформенно-специфические возможности, требуемые конкретным приложением.
2. У вас уже есть библиотека, написанная на другом языке, и вы хотите использовать ее в JAVA.
3. Вы хотите реализовать некоторые участки кода, критичные к скорости исполнения, на языке более низкого уровня типа Ассемблера.

Пример: граф обработки аудио/видео с фильтрами. Фильтр имеет интерфейс JAVA-объекта, а алгоритм конкретного фильтра реализован на C/ASM и подключается с помощью JNI.